# Accessing static properties in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

With the following code in mind

**a.coffee**

```
B = require './b'
C = require './c'

console.log B.someStaticVar
C.checkB()
```

**b.coffee**

```
C = require './c'

class B
  @someStaticVar: 1

module.exports = B;
```

**c.coffee**

```
B = require './b'

class C
  @checkB: ->
    console.log B.someStaticVar

module.exports = C
```

I am trying to understand why the static property of **b** is undefined when accessed by **c** but returning **1** when accessed by **a**

**Output:**

```
$ coffee a.coffee
1
undefined
```

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle demonstrating the problem? I'm guessing your code above is simplified and may have abstracted away your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a circular reference.

1. A loads B
2. B loads C
3. C loads B

   - But B isn't done loading, so here it's an empty object
4. C finishes loading
5. B finishes loading
6. A loads C - it's already loaded so it just gets a reference.
7. A finishes loading, your `console.log` lines at the end of the file are executed.

Here is a version of your 3 modules that illustrates this better:

**a.coffee**

```
B = require './b'
C = require './c'
console.log B.someStaticVar
C.checkB()
```

**b.coffee**

```
C = require './c'
console.log 'in b.coffee, we have loaded C: ', C
class B
  @someStaticVar: 1
module.exports = B;
```

**c.coffee**

```
B = require './b'
console.log 'in c.coffee, we have loaded B: ', B
class C
  @checkB: ->
    console.log B.someStaticVar
module.exports = C
```

---

You have two options for fixing this cyclic dependency in commonjs:

### 1. Lazy loading

Don't require `./b` in `c.coffee` until you execute your function. By the time you call `C.checkB` inside `a.coffee` B will have been fully loaded and the correct class will be returned from the require call

```
class C
  @checkB: ->
    B = require './b'
    console.log B.someStaticVar

module.exports = C
```

### 2. Refactoring

`B` and `C` are tightly coupled. Consider rewriting them to be contained within a single file. You could just remove the `require './c'` from `b.coffee`. Though I'm guessing it's in this example as your code is more complex and does have a need for it.

**a.coffee**

```
{ B, C } = require './b'

console.log B.someStaticVar
C.checkB()
```

**b.coffee**

```
class B
  @someStaticVar: 1

class C
  @checkB: ->
    console.log B.someStaticVar

module.exports = 
  C: C
  B: B
```